# Best practice to handle different group of users accessing their own content

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am building a web app where different companies will upload their own audio files with some additional information. I am building it using Django, Postgres and hosting it on AWS. Users belong to different companies will only be able to access their data when they log into the website.

The website allows those users to upload content, search content and access content.

My question is, what's the best practice to handle those uploaded content? Is it better to create different schema for each company or putting all the content together and allow users to access different content based on the company id that each entry associates with?

Answer (score 1):

> putting all the content together and allow users to access different content based on the company id that each entry associates with?

Personally, I would do this, for several reasons:

1. It's easier to maintain. Adding new companies probably just means a new ID, rather than a new schema and some tables.
2. You can add security with application code or with database views.
3. You can have other company specific functionality that uses the same design.

I would also suggest enforcing the data security on the database side, by only allowing the application to query from certain views, where the views are limited by company ID. This means that you won't accidentally SELECT from a base table and forget the company filter, causing the user to see data that isn't theirs.

This is just my opinion - happy to be proven otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! The reason that I was considering the option of creating multiple schemas is that I am not sure about how to enforce data security for different queries within the same database. This might be a long shot, but do you happen to know any good resources for implementing this? I have been trying to google search for this but I haven't come across anything that is directly relevant.